# Why do some sites show themes/"themename" as the only theme?

Tags: theme-development, themes

While inspecting some sites built with WordPress, I noticed that in some cases the themes folder is named - themes/"themename". And instead of there being multiple themes inside this folder, there is simply the root of the single theme. Is this common practice when only one theme is being used? Or is there something I'm not noticing. See below screenshot for reference.

[image: Example]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't remotely inspect site's files and directories. That's not what's happening here. The browser inspector is just reconstructing the structure based on the URLs of resources that it is loading.

The browser sees that `/wp-content/themes/themename/style.css` is being loaded, and `/wp-content/plugins/plugin/style.css` and assumes that there must be `/wp-content/themes/` and `wp-content/plugins/` directories. So it creates a file browser for you based on this structure.

This also means that it is only showing files that the browser is loading. This is not a full (or necessarily accurate) view of the actual file structure on the server.

And the reason that `themes/webdesingsun` is being shown as a single folder, is simply because the browser is only loading resources from one directory in `/themes/`, so it's saving you the trouble of having to expand the only folder in `/themes/`.

Answer (score 0):

In general you should not have themes and plugins that you do not actively use as this is a potential security hole (for example you are less likely to spend the time to upgrade them)

Comment: Yes, I understand security, but the question was more about whether or not this is a best practice in file structure, and if there are parent themes that are hidden. I've added a screenshot to my original question that might clarify things.

Comment: not sure about "best practice" here. If you have only one theme, that is most likely the directory structure you will see. If there are no other themes then it is unlikely to be a child theme.

Comment: ..... but I would guess that you are trying to guess from a URL: structure about how sites are made, which is not something that you can always easily deduct.